# How to make chrome use less system memory in ubuntu

Tags: 14.04, google-chrome

I have ubuntu 14.04LTS installed with web development tools like LAMP package. When I work on firefox system runs smoothly, but when I start chrome system start utilizing lot of Memory and CPU. Even chrome get hang. Is there any way to optimize chrome browser to make it work like firefox without utilizing lot of system resources.

Comment: I guess not. If you have any add-ons installed in Chrome, you could try to disable or uninstall them. Or try the open-source alternative `chromium` from the official Ubuntu repositories.

Comment: Well, Chromium is in `universe`. And software in `universe` is "Community maintained software, i.e. not officially supported software". See https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories/Ubuntu. So to that extent, I'd be hesistant to say that chromium is in the "official" Ubuntu repositories.

Comment: Maybe you can find some useful hints here: http://www.howtogeek.com/216171/how-to-make-google-chrome-use-less-battery-life-memory-and-cpu/

Answer (score 3):

Try to install extension "The Great Suspender" in chrome. It suspends automaticaly unused tabs. Maybe it will conserve some RAM for you.